How to enforce snake_case naming for class and id attributes in Vue <template> elements?
I am working on a Vue.js project and want to ensure that the class and id attributes inside the <template> section follow the snake_case naming convention. Currently, I am using ESLint for enforcing code style, but it doesn't validate the values of these HTML attributes.
For example, I want the following:
<template>
  <div class="my_class" id="another_id"> <!-- Should pass -->
    <p class="NotValidClass">Hello</p> <!-- Should trigger an error -->
  </div>
</template>

Is there a way to configure ESLint or create a custom rule to enforce this naming convention for class and id attributes?
The only thing I found was
"camelcase": [
                "error",
                {
                     "properties": "always"
                }
            ],

but it only works for functions and variables inside of <script> and I wonder if there is similar rule for <template>
